# How to enable/disable audio device with hotkey?

Tags: windows, audio, 64-bit

How would I add a hotkey to toggle on/off an audio device of choice in Windows 7 x64?

Here is an image of Windows 7 sound dialog window > playback tab to audio devices.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SU, we're not a script writing service.  What have you got so far?  Where exactly are you getting stuck?

Comment: well. I don't know where to begin. It doesn't have to be an AHK script. I just can't figure out a way to enable/disable an audio device (of choice) with a hotkey.

Comment: Must the audio device be disabled or can the audio simply be muted?

Comment: Yes, it must be "disabled" reason being to eliminate the need to manually switch speaker output with Skype. (this is primarily Skype's fault for being featureless)

Comment: Even if SU was a script writing service, your question is way too vague for anyone to answer it.

Comment: You will have more luck stating the root problem / desired function than asking about some dead end you reached while working on it. Note that Windows itself has options to mute certain outputs while a call is taking place. (The communications tab in the Sound control panel).

Comment: @Brian I don't need a mute option (I already know a way to do so). I specifically just need a hotkey to "DISABLE" an audio device (of choice). I switch between headphone and speaker from different outputs (built-in sound card is horrible-too many interference [hiss]). I have hotkeys to switch audio outputs, problem is Skype doesn't switch along with it (because of no default audio device option), rather it's priority device set (in hierarchy order).

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention Skype which is usually used to place calls: What do you have the Communications tab of the Windows Sound control panel set to?

[image]

Comment: completely irrelevant, but it's set to "Do nothing". my main intentions for disabling an audio device is so that Skype can use the next remaining device. This is because Skype doesn't have a "Default Device" option for speaker output.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use [AudioSwitcher](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/audio-switcher-hotkey-switch-between-audio-devices). Work wonders for me :).